# Does MPLAB IDE v8.92 show Page Breaks anywhere in programmer

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, mplab

In the MPLAB assembly code window is their anyway to show or indicate where page breaks are I am using 50 PClath Calls.
 If I add or remove code it changes the position of page breaks. I would like to know where the page breaks are, if shown in any of the windows provided in MPLAB.  Page refers to memory allocation block boundaries. In code their is no defined points where they start are end.

Comment: Are you planing to actually print your source code? On actual paper?? Didn't that sort of behavior stop around the time of the abacus, or punch-cards or something? ;)

Comment: Each block of memory has a starting and stopping point. Page refers to these blocks.

Comment: Ok - that's unusual usage of the term "page breaks" in my experience ... but what you're looking for is specific to the particular device you're writing code for and will be found in its datasheet.

Comment: ... and what's a "Plath Call"?

Comment: It is suppose to be PClath sorry! PClath sets page to goto.

Comment: If you look at the Program Memory window and List file *.lst you should be able to find what you need.

Comment: The ".lst" is exactly what I needed. If you could put the comment in the answer question box it would be good.

Comment: If you use the PAGESEL macro before each call, you don't had to wonder about the page.

Comment: i know I did not specify Micro-Controller but pic18f2550 does not use PAGESEL at least anywhere I could find in datasheet or Assembly Instructions for this CHIP.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the List file ***.lst** you should be able to find what you need. – Spehro Pefhany Aug 20 at 17:38. I posted this for **Spehro Pefhany** as this is the answer I was looking for. I ask him to enter it but he did not.

```
000730                00775 DEFAULT_WAITING:
000730 26F9           00776         addwf   PCL,f   
000732 0C53 0C61 0C76 00777         dt "Saving  Default",0 

MPASM  5.51                    LCD_DS1307.ASM   8-20-2018  14:53:11         PAGE 20

MPASM  5.51                    LCD_DS1307.ASM   8-20-2018  14:53:11         PAGE 21

MPASM  5.51                    LCD_DS1307.ASM   8-20-2018  14:53:11         PAGE 22

000798                00788              READ_WAITING_TEXT_SUB:                        
000798 82FA           00789              BSF     PCLATH,1 Text for 2nd Line   
00079A 84FA           00790              BSF     PCLATH,2        
00079C EC?? F???      00791              CALL    WAITING_TEXT 
0007A0 92FA           00792              BCF     PCLATH,1
0007A2 94FA           00793              BCF     PCLATH,2 
0007A4 0012           00794              RETURN
```